# How do I write a sample space notationally, given a combination?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, notation

Say I have $\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3, ... \beta_n$. How do I write the notation for the sample space of, say, the products of $nC2$ of them, i.e. {$(\beta_1*\beta_2),(\beta_1*\beta_3),...(\beta_{n-1}*\beta_n)$}? I want to be able to iterate through the list, and be able to multiply each of those elements in that sample space by some function, for example.

Comment: As you want combinations, the pairs $\beta_i \beta_j$ where $i < j$ should do it.

Comment: $\{\beta_i * \beta_j : i<j\}$